# How to make membership optional in Civicrm sign up form?

Tags: webforms, civicrm

I am using [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module with [Civicrm](https://civicrm.org/download/list).

I have a registration form. This latter could be used to become member of an organization. However, I would like to make this membership optional.

How could I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use some conditional logic in the form so that if someone wants to sign up the relevant section of the form is shown?

Comment: Also, did you know there is now a dedicated Stack Exchange site for CiviCRM: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com